# Add a component to all react-routes but one

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to apply a header to all pages but home. What would be the better approach to do this? I don't want to copy the header for every new page.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/">
    <Home />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/about">
    <Header />
    <About />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/users">
    <Header />
    <Users />
  </Route>         
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a different approach without having to track `location` like in the other post, - hopefully it can help someone:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route render={() =>
      <>
        <Header /> // --> header component will be present whenever a route is not matching the '/' route
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
        </Switch>
      </>
    }} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: Yeah, to tell the truth previous approach doesn't work, props.location.pathname isn't approachable outside of router, and window.location.pathname hasn't been updating when we click links. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using react-router you could access the `location.pathname` property of `props` and then only render it on certain pathnames.

```
<div>
 {props.location.pathname !== '/' && <Header />}
 <Switch> 
   <Route path="/">
     <Home />
   </Route>
   <Route path="/about">
     <About />
   </Route>
   <Route path="/users">
     <Users />
   </Route>         
 </Switch>
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers! One thing is you can't use location path outside of Route but window.location.pathname solved the problem.